# Template is missing: Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, missing-template

> Missing template `contact_mailer/contact_email` with "mailer". Searched in: * "contact_mailer"

I get this error when sending a contact form from my website. I'm not sure what I've done wrong or forgotten. Would some please be so kind to assist me? And maybe educate me a tad on whats going on here? My repo [GitREPO](https://github.com/joshuahiskraken/Website)

Comment: Add the full error stack.

Comment: Are you sure its not just a typo? The file seems to be named contact_mailer as well. Try renaming it to contact_email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When mailing `ContactMailer.contact_email` view should be named the same as action - `contact_mailer/contact_email.html.erb`, but yours is named `contact_mailer/contact_mailer.html.erb`, thus it is not found.

Comment: Thanks alot for that! Kudos to you